# bean scope with prototype is throwing BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a class defined as below

```
public class Caller {

    private GreetingService greetingService;
    private String name;

    public Caller(GreetingService greetingService) {
        System.out.println("Inside the constructor of Caller");
        this.greetingService = greetingService;

    }

    public void invokeGreet(String message) {
        greetingService.greet(message, "Pradeep");
    }

    public void myCustomInit() {
        System.out.println("Came inside the custom initializer method");
    }

    public void myCustomDestroy() {
        System.out.println("Came inside the custom destroy function..");
    }
}
```

`GreetingService` is an Interface

```
public interface GreetingService {


    public void greet(String message, String name);
}
```

AwesomeGreet class:

```
public class AwesomeGreet implements GreetingService {

    private String salutation;


    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }


    public void setSalutation(String salutation) {
        this.salutation = salutation;
    }


    public void greet(String message, String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello !! "+salutation+" " +name +" "+message);
    }

}
```

My `application-context.xml` file looks like below:

```
<bean id="caller" class="com.classpath.spring.Caller" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg name="greetingService"
             ref="awesomeGreet" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="awesomeGreet" class="com.classpath.spring.AwesomeGreet" scope="prototype">
        <property name="salutation" value="Mr"></property>
    </bean>
```

When I try to load the `application-context`, I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.classpath.spring.Caller]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:299)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    ... 14 more
```

I am not sure, where am I going wrong. The same example works fine when the scope is set to Singleton.

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution?

Comment: No. I moved on.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the bean definition should have `class="com.classpath.spring.GreetingService"`

Comment: For which tag, I need to put the above mentioned attribute?

Comment: `<bean id="awesomeGreet"`

Comment: No, It does not work that way since the class should point to the concrete class and not the Interface.

Comment: Caller constructor takes an argument of type `GreetingService`, so try changing the bean definition of `awesomeGreet`, finally spring will create an instance of the implementation while injecting.